# Advaita (Adi Shankara) School : Word to word meaning (bhashya) of Upanishads

Tags: advaita, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya

I asked this question in Quora too but could not get any answers. I hope someone could help me.

I love to read Upanishads bhashya translated as per Advaita School. I am looking for bhashyam where it mentions original sanskrit verses along with word-to-word english meaning.

Can someone please suggest which publications and authors have given such titles?

Thank you.

Comment: There are many..

Answer (score 2):

Sripad Adi Shankaracharya who popularized the philosophy of Advaita Vedanta has written commentary upon 10 Mukhya Upanishads.

1.[Commentary on Upanishads with Shankara Bhasya Vol 1 (Isa,Kena,Katha,Taittiriya)](https://b-ok.asia/book/5705400/cb6542)

(open above epub file on web using [this](https://www.fviewer.com/view-epub))

2.[Commentary on Upanishads with Shankara Bhasya Vol 2(Aitareya,Mundaka,Mandukya,Karika,Prasna)](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Eight-Upanisads-vol2.pdf)

3.[Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upanishad Shankara Bhasya](https://ia800302.us.archive.org/2/items/Brihadaranyaka.Upanishad.Shankara.Bhashya.by.Swami.Madhavananda/Brihadaranyaka.Upanishad.Shankara.Bhashya.by.Swami.Madhavananda.pdf)

4.[Chāndogya Upanishad Sanskrit Shlokas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english) with [Shankara Bhasya.](https://ia800301.us.archive.org/29/items/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English.pdf)